# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: 'unrecognized selector sent to class '

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, compiler-errors

When I try to use the MLModelInterpreter from Firebase to load a tflite-File in my Xcode project I'm getting the following error after the Launchsreen is fully visible:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10235ca58
```

My code is based on the tutorial from Firebase, thus I’m surprised that it doesn’t work. Here is the code:

```
import Firebase


    var interpreter: ModelInterpreter?

    func convertTheModel(){


        guard let modelPath = Bundle.main.path( forResource: "model", ofType: "tflite", inDirectory: ""
            )
            else {
                print("not able to load model")
                return

        }

        let localModel = CustomLocalModel(modelPath: modelPath)
        interpreter =  ModelInterpreter.modelInterpreter(localModel: localModel)

        let ioOptions = ModelInputOutputOptions()
        do {
            try ioOptions.setInputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 22])
            try ioOptions.setOutputFormat(index: 0, type: .float32, dimensions: [1, 1])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to set input or output format with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }



    let inputs = ModelInputs()
    var inputData = Data()

        do {
            for _ in 0 ..< 22 {

              // require fixed-point values or the original bytes.
              var RandomNumber = Float.random(in: 0 ..< 1)

              // Append normalized values to Data object.
              let elementSize = MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: RandomNumber)
              var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: elementSize)
              memcpy(&bytes, &RandomNumber, elementSize)
              inputData.append(&bytes, count: elementSize)
          }
          try inputs.addInput(inputData)
        } catch let error {
          print("Failed to add input: \(error)")
        }


        interpreter!.run(inputs: inputs, options: ioOptions) { outputs, error in
            guard error == nil, let outputs = outputs else { return }

            print(outputs)
        }

    }
```

After some debugging I have a vague guess that the error is caused by this line of code:
`interpreter =  ModelInterpreter.modelInterpreter(localModel: localModel)`

**Additional Information**

Before the issue described above I had another issue: When building the project the compiler showed this error:

```
/Users/Path/Application_Name/Update/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/Detector/Frameworks/GoogleMobileVision.framework/GoogleMobileVision(VisionExtension.pbobjc_0848a2b53cac8a49ea32ab4e6cb931d4.o)
ld: 46 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
```

Here is a summary of what I did:

1. I cleaned the buildingfolder
2. Reinstall all pods:  `pod deintegrate` and than `pod install`
3. set No Common Blocks to no
4. remove all -ObjC  as in [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com) described.

My Podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'My Project' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for My Project
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleMobileVision/FaceDetector'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/MLModelInterpreter'


end
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help

**Edit**

If anybody has an other solution to load an tflite-file (or an h5-file: check out my previous Question) into an Xcode project it would be also helpful

@ Paul Beusterien

This Is the location where I pasted the `-ObjC`:
[image]

Comment: Firstly do you understand what the `unrecognised selector` exception means?

Comment: Firstly thank you for the immediat response. I do not understand it in detail, but I  understood that selector is a relic from the past, from Objective-C. It selects which function to execute on an object based on the selector.  ([Information](https://learnappmaking.com/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-swift-development/)) How does this informatin help to solve my issue?

Comment: Well a selector is another name for method.  What the exception means is that you tried to call a method on an object that does not have that method.  In other words you are using the wrong object.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/139) might be the problem.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks I'll check it out

Comment: @trojanfoe I checked it out. But it was quiet frustrating. I was even sturggeling with the first point. I'm currently not having a paid developper account. That's why I can't set up de Firebase Massaging tool. Thus I can't follow this tutorial. Do you have an other idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: As in the "edit" described: An other way to implement a tflite-file would be helpful as well.

Comment: Does Firebase have a Massaging tool? I should try that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-ObjC must be in the app's `Other Linker Flags` for Firebase to work correctly. See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4776 for more details about this issue.

Comment: I tried it out but I was running in the same issus  as described in the Question: `ld: 46 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)` . It could be that I added  `-ObjC` on the wrong `Other Linker Flags` . I pasted on the Podstarget File: (Picture in my Question) Is that correct?

Comment: It should be the app's project settings not the Pods project.  If you're still getting the duplicate symbols problem, share the details ...

Comment: I tried it but I'm facing the same issue as described in the Question. Do you have any idea how to solve it. Neither run into the building error nor the other crash error?

Comment: I'd need to see more details about the duplicate symbols error